# Print all links that may contain any of the words from a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to print all links from a webpage that contains a word from a list of words. I got the list of links that contains the word 'contact' using Beautifulsoup and the code goes like below.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links = link.get('href')
    if 'contact' in links:
        print links
```

But how can I print links with the following condition

```
keywords = ("contact", "reach", "feedback", "address")
if links contain any words from keywords: ## this is not actual code
   print links;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a duplicate, though I'm on mobile so I'm having difficulty finding another question that answers yours.

In brief, what you probably want is a list comprehension and `any`

```
if any( [word in links for word in keywords] )
```

`any` returns True if there's at least one True value in the list (which, fun tidbit, is basically functionally equivalent to `sum` because of how Python casts Booleans to ints). And the list comprehension generates a Boolean list for all evaluations of the keyword being in the link.

Edit:

Thanks to @COLDSPEED, the brackets may be dropped.

Comment: You can drop the `[` and `]`